# Jade Messaging Queue - Eclipse

Tags: java, agents-jade

How I would like to change these parameters from eclipse (**not using command line**):

```
jade_core_messaging_MessageManager_poolsize
jade_core_messaging_MessageManager_maxqueuesize
jade_core_messaging_MessageManager_deliverytimethreshold
```

The first changes the number of threads that handle the queue size, the second changes the max queue size of the received ACL messages, and finally the last changes when to print a warning when the delivery time threshold is exceeded.

bests,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start your container and agents programmatically, then something like this

```
    jade.core.Runtime rt = jade.core.Runtime.instance();

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("local-port", "8858");
    properties.put("port", "8858");
    properties.put("host", "127.0.0.1");
    properties.put("local-host", "127.0.0.1");
    .... other parameters
    properties.put("jade_core_messaging_MessageManager_poolsize", "100");

    ProfileImpl p = new ProfileImpl(properties);
    rt.setCloseVM(true);
    AgentContainer agentContainer = rt.createMainContainer(p);

    AgentController ac = agentContainer.createNewAgent("YourAgent", YourAgent.class.getName(), new Object[]{});
    ac.start();
```

Comment: If this works you will be a life saver. I have one question though, the agent I am focusing on, i.e the one I want to have these properties, is created to by another agent using the createNewAgent() method (in your example, "Your Agent" will create a "NewAgent") . Also, this created agent ("NewAgent") will move to another container and execute, should I add these properties to the destination container ?